# Add delay between adding 2 classes

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to build an accordion like UI. I need to add delay between adding to classes. and for some reason, it's not happening.

Here is the html

```
        <div class="page page2">
            <div class="pagetop">
                <div class="toptxt toptext2">
                 Top tab
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pagecnt"></div>
        </div>
```

The css

```
.page {
margin-top:6px;
position: relative;
height:67px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.openpage {
 position:absolute;
 top:330px;
}
.openpage2 {
height:auto;
overflow: visible;
}
```

and the jquery

```
    $(".pagetop").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass('openpage');
               setTimeout(function(){
               $(this).parent().addClass('openpage2');
            },20000);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Well, there is no difference between `.openpage` and `.openpage2`. Both has `height: auto` and `overflow: visible`.

Comment: shoot... i need to get some sleep. I've corrected the css, but .openpage2 still is not added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `$(this)` inside setTimeout refers to `window` object.
You could fix it by using a closure. like the following example.

```js
$(".pagetop").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var self = this;
        $(this).parent().addClass('openpage');
           setTimeout(function(){
           $(self).parent().addClass('openpage2');
        },2000);
    });
});
```

```css
.page {
  margin-top: 6px;
  position: relative;
  height: 67px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.openpage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 330px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
.openpage2 {
  background: red;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page page2">
  <div class="pagetop">
    <div class="toptxt toptext2">
      Top tab
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pagecnt"></div>
</div>
```